# Simple_form is NOT showing any message when updating the form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using below simple_form in _form.html.erb which I am rendering in edit.html.erb, when editing the form, it do edit the fields but doesn't show any message that the form has been updated. I am very surprised why is this happening ? any help ?

```
<%= simple_form_for(@info, remote: true, :html => {class: 'form-horizontal'}) do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.input :phone %>
    <%= f.input :email %>
    <%= f.button :submit, class: 'btn btn-success' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: update you question with the update.erb.js file.. when submiting a form with ajax it's not the same as doing with a html request, you need to get the message from browser headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extracted from my project:

**_flash_notices.html.erb**

```
<div class="noticesWrapper">
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
  <div class="alert alert-<%= name == :notice ? "success" : "error" %>">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a>
    <%= msg %>
  </div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

! see the noticesWrapper element, as you'll need to render your notification inside of it.

**application_controller.rb**

```
  after_filter :add_flash_to_header

  def add_flash_to_header
    # only run this in case it's an Ajax request.
    return unless request.xhr?

    # add different flashes to header
    response.headers['X-Flash-Error'] = flash[:error] unless flash[:error].blank?
    response.headers['X-Flash-Warning'] = flash[:warning] unless flash[:warning].blank?
    response.headers['X-Flash-Notice'] = flash[:notice] unless flash[:notice].blank?
    response.headers['X-Flash-Message'] = flash[:message] unless flash[:message].blank?

    # make sure flash does not appear on the next page
    flash.discard
  end
```

**update.js.erb**

```
$('.noticesWrapper').html("<%= j(render partial: 'layouts/flash_notices') %>");
```

**your_controller.rb**

```
  def update
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])

    if @project.update_attributes(params[:project])
      flash.now[:notice] = "Project updated"
     else
        flash.now[:error] = "Project not updated"
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying, I am little confused, what is that application_controller.rb code doing ? can you explain me the control flow

Comment: had the same issue as yours a while ago, couldn't get flash messages to show when doing an ajax request, so I've looked for a ton of solutions and this one worked for me, from what I understood this code in application controller sets the notice in the response headers of the browser so you can extract them from there.. more about this http://blog.project-sierra.de/archives/1808

Comment: should it be edit.js.erb or form.js.erb ? since the form code is in _form.html.erb and I am rendering it in edit.html.erb ?

Comment: alright i have put the code but it is not working, as I have not edited anything in _form.html.erb ? do I need to insert noticesWrapper with div somewhere ?

Comment: the name of the js.erb file should be the same as the action name, if your action is called update, means you need an update.js.erb file and there you do the js stuff

Comment: and also in the controller don't forget to change flash[:notice] to flash.now[:notice]

Comment: let me know if you still have problems with it, I'll try to help you with is as much as I can

Comment: thanks mate, unfortunately it is still not working :( OK, lets try to find the problem. Is there any way I can see any error being thrown ? also after editing, the page remains at /info/1/edit. can I atleast redirect to /info/1 (i.e. show page) ? as I will be fine with that too as /info/1 do show the edited content

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30597/discussion-between-rmagnum2002-and-icyborg)

Comment: Did you manged to solve your task? I wrote you in the chat to contact me by mail for further help.

Comment: The blog link are down @rmagnum2002.

Comment: @FernandoKosh looks like stackoverflow.com doesn't keep the chat history for that long, it's a 8 years long answer.

Comment: Yes, but i'm talking about this one: http://blog.project-sierra.de/archives/1808